# mysql illegal mix of collations for update using integers only

Tags: mysql

I have checked many articles but haven't found the answer. Closest to this is article 49388342, but is uses select.

Database version is 8.0.29.
Collations are:

- collation_connection utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
- collation_database utf8_unicode_ci
- collation_server utf8_unicode_ci

Problematic table has collation utf8_general_ci, and all its char columns have the same collation.
I want to execute simple update of one int column using int PK. So, no chars anywhere.

`update table1 set validity = 121 where id = 5`

I get famous error: *Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='*

To exclude that the issue is on where part, I tried update without where, same error.
When I tried to force collation on integer value 121, nothing. I also changed collation_connection to be as that of the table. Nothing.
Whatever I tried, I had no luck.
At the same time, production database, version 8.0.25 has no issue with this update.

Also, one other table with all the same collations as the table above (char columns) has no issue when I try to update one of its int columns, using int PK id. No chars anywhere.

As far as I understand, database runs update with the collation of the table and ignores any of my attempts to push desired collation inside of the statement. Since I work only with integers, collations are not applicable to them.

Any ideas?

Edit: for those who still would like to see the structure of the table, here it is. I have left out a bunch of irrelevant integer fields. All relevant fields, all varchar fields, indexes, keys as shown here. Table has 3 triggers, for insert, update, delete. They don't do any data manipulation in this table but on some other to indicate there were changes in this table.

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (

  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,

  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',

  `description_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,

  `validity` int NOT NULL,

  `active_from` datetime NOT NULL,

  `active_to` datetime NOT NULL,

  `status` int NOT NULL,

  `type` int DEFAULT NULL,

  `group` int DEFAULT '1',

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),

  KEY `idx_table1_date_from` (`active_from`,`active_to`,`status`),

  KEY `idx_table1_type` (`type`),

  KEY `idx_table1_group` (`group`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12211 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Insert trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` TRIGGER `cache_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    call updateCache( 'TABLE1' );
END
```

Procedure updateCache executes statement:

```
UPDATE `cache` SET `timestamp` = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() WHERE `name` = tbl_name;
```

Comment: Does `validity` datatype is numeric? Check in CREATE TABLE. Does the parameters are really provided as numeric literals? Check in General Log. Does some trigger exists? Check its code.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In the meantime, I did this test...
I created another table with create table statement of affected table. Then I filled it with all the data from the original. Now update works on this table.

Comment: Today I altered collation of the table to be the same as database and server, utf8_unicode_ci.
```alter table table1 convert to character set utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;```
It didn't help, error message is the same so I changed collation back to as it was.

Comment: I have created mysql bug report for this.

Comment: In the end, it turned out it was not a bug.
The source of the problem was a trigger that was used further in the chain of operations. After I figured that out and adjusted that trigger, the problem was resolved.